# Ошибка при понижении версии api

Tags: android, android-studio

изменил **Min sdk version** на **api 10** , до этого была **14** и все работало. Теперь при компиляции вылетает вот такая ошибка:

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01] C:\Users\Alexey\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-28.0.0-rc01.aar\e27109d363cc548c265f876c2abf641e\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 10
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 10,
    or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 14,
    or use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.design" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Вот содержимое файла **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.liverpoll.tabak.a1cmobit"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01'
}
```

Я так понимаю проблема в этих библиотеках? Что нужно сделать, чтобы заработало?

Comment: Судя по ошибке, библиотека использует методы на API 14+. И вам советуют либо вернуть в проект 14+ или найти другую библиотеку. Как вариант - покопаться в ее исходниках и изменить методы (не факт, что всё будет работать как нужно). Вообще, сейчас даже 14 уже не актуально, ее использует менее 1% пользователей: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/?hl=ru

Comment: У нынешних суппортных библиотек `minSdk 14`. Что бы понизить версию нужно брать древние версии, которые её поддерживали. Ещё можно попробовать вписать в манифест (по рекомендации в ошибке) `tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.design"` и надеяться что прокатит (если нигде не задействован критичный код - в чём я сильно сомневаюсь). Ну или не использовать суппорты вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Что **можно** сделать, написано прямо в тексте ошибки: использовать

```
tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.design"
```

Но лучше так не делать, потому что неизвестно какие проблемы потом возникнут (т.е. известно - приложение может вылетать прямо в процессе использования).

Поэтому лучше всего вернуть minSdk на 14.  Это ведь Андроид 4.0. Таких уже никто не помнит.